# Deploy a node.js application to Bluemix using cf command line interface failed

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

The error message I got

> -----> Build failed
>   Your build failed!
>   Some possible problems:
>   - node_modules checked into source control
>   https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html#should-i-check-my-node_modules-> > folder-into-git-
>   Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
>   FAILED
>   BuildpackCompileFailed

How to fix this problem?

Comment: What arguments did you use when pushing? What's in the `manifest.yml` file?

Answer (score 1):

As a user, I would first check whether node_modules is placed in .cfignore file and .gitignore, if the project resides in a git repository, in the project. Similar to [.gitignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git-Staging), [.cfignore](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html) file specifies files not required to build the application. Files in node_modules are not needed to be uploaded to Bluemix application instance, therefore, can be placed in file .cfignore and .gitignore.